# How to pass parameter from another php file using wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've a post type called "rooms" and there is a meta variable like `$max_person` for every room. In `single-rooms.php`
all what I need is to pass `$max_person` to an external `javascript` file

This is what I wrote in `function.php` -

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {

    if (is_single()) {
        if (get_post_type() == 'rooms') {
            $max_person = get_post_meta($post->ID,'max_person',true);
            $combo_parameters = array(
                'max' => $max_person
            );

            wp_enqueue_script('room_combobox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/room_combobox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' ,true);
            wp_localize_script( 'room_combobox', 'ComboParameters', $combo_parameters );

        }
    }
});
```

and this is my javascript file

```
function room_combobox() {
    var text = "";
    var i;
    var x =  ComboParameters.max;

    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        text += "<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>" +"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("combo").innerHTML = '<select name= "room-adults" id= "single-room-adult-selection"><option>No. adults</option>'+text+x+'</select>';
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    room_combobox()
});
```

for some reasons ComboParameters.max = 0

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` of the `$combo_parameters` variable to check if it has the data you expect? One potential issue I see is that you didn't declare the `$post` variable as global.

Comment: @DominicP how can i declare `$post` as global variable

Comment: Add `global $post;` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: @DominicP ThnQ it works fine :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked. I added the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `$post` variable wasn't declared as global, so `get_post_meta` failed because it wasn't passed a valid post ID.

Just add `global $post` to the beginning of the function to reference the global variable.

See php docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php